# Display rotates before browser orientationchange fires

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, orientation-changes

I have two distinctly different presentations of a page, depending on landscape or portrait orientation. The first img on that page is assigned (via javascript) a landscape or portrait proportioned src depending on the orientation. This works on Safari, Chrome ,Firefox on all test desktop machines (Windows/Mac), all tested Android devices using Chrome or Firefox, and IOS iPads - where it breaks is on iPhone 5/6 (probably 7).

In the .ready javascript code I blank the page using $("body").css("visibility","hidden"), do my formatting, set the "src" of the image to portraitformatpicture.jpg or landscapeformatpicture.jpg and then renable the screen with $("body").css("visibility","visible").

This method actually works in all instances - rotating the device causes the screen to go blank, after which the properly orient image appears.

The issue is only on IOS Safari on iPhones - when the device is rotated you see the current page displayed in the new orientation, with the other (previous) orientation's image displayed. You see the new orientation displaying the page flipped sideways for "a while" (100s of milliseconds) at which point the "orientationchange" event fires in the browser, allowing the javascript to run, which correctly switches the image and formatting.

So the problem isn't that the orientationchange event doesn't occur, it's that the page is visible before any of the orientation-specific logic has had a chance to run.

How have any other folks addressed this? There is no notification that I'm aware of that can inform the javascript that a screen orientation change is imminent, only that one has already occured...

Comment: Please post code if you'd like help on this forum.

Comment: The code in this case is not relevant - the code is functional as I described. It is the TIMING of the notification relative to what the browser is doing that is in question. The IOS Safari browser on an iPhone acts first THEN notifies the javascript. For some this is undoubtedly a cosmetic issue that can be overlooked, in this case it cannot.